# How to customize swagger url based on internet ip?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, swagger

I'm using swagger for my ASP.NET WebAPI Services. I want to show the documentation page.

When I want to show the Swagger UI, I have to call this url: http://sample.com:5000/swagger/index.html, but url is based on internal network http://192.168.175.4:5000/swagger/index.html, where can I config this url

[image]

Comment: I assume you are hosting the web application on IIS, if that is the case, you could try to configure the IIS to access website using IP address: In the **Connections** pane of **IIS**, expand the Sites and select the website which you want to access via IP address. Click on the **Bindings** link and you will see current bindings of that website. Click on **Add** button to add a new binding. On the Add Site Binding window, keep website Type as http. Select an IP address from the drop-down menu upon which you want to bind the website, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwtMU.png).

Comment: yes, I am hosting the api on IIS, I set bindings so that you said but it was not corrected